# Javascript & PHP drop down lists

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently working on a website that offers a customised menu section.

There are 5 separate drop down boxes that contains a separate list in each. There is a plus box added to each list box, when the plus box is clicked it is meant to add another list box (identical list data from the list box it was added from) below it.

The issue I have is that all the plus signs work but only add the list box under the "starter options" section and only use the "starter option" data. So I need it to work so that if a plus is clicked from the "Breakfast Option" it adds the same list box below it. Then if the plus box is clicked on the "starter option" section a box is then added below it and so on.

I've made a separate JS for each section area, I am wondering if this is the issue and it needs to be one script, but I am unsure. This is the a current working piece of the code
http://khushicatering.co.uk/menu_fi.php . I will add the code below for the form and the JS's.

HTML FORM

```
                    <div id="splitter">
                      <table width="250" border="0">
                        <tr>
                          <td width="311"><span class="asdwd">
                            <label>Breakfast Menu</label>
                          </span></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td><div id="break"></div>
                            <select name="text[]">
                              <option value="Bhature ">Bhature </option>
                              <option value="Chana Amrtisari">Chana Amrtisari</option>
                              <option value="Masala Dhai">Masala Dhai</option>
                              <option value="Mithai">Mithai</option>
                              <option value="Palak Pakora">Palak Pakora</option>
                              <option value="Paranthe">Paranthe</option>
                              <option value="Punjabi Samosa">Punjabi Samosa</option>
                              <option value="&lt;none&gt;">&lt;none&gt;</option>
                            </select>
                            <input type="button" id="submit2" onClick="addNew();"
       value=" + ">
                            </p>
                            <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                    </div> <div id="splitter">
                      <table width="250" border="0">
                        <tr>
                          <td width="250"><span class="asdwd">
                            <label>Starter Options</label>
                          </span></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td><div id="start"></div>
                            <select name="text[]">
                              <option value="Aloo Tikki">Aloo Tikki</option>
                              <option value="Channa Masala">Channa Masala</option>
                              <option value="Chicken Pakora ">Chicken Pakora </option>
                              <option value="Chicken Seekh Kebabs">Chicken Seek   Kebabs</option>
                              <option value="Chicken Tikka Malai">Chicken Tikka Malai</option>
                              <option value="Chicken Tikka Masala">Chicken Tikka Masala</option>
                              <option value="Chilli Chicken">Chilli Chicken</option>
                              <option value="Chilli Mogo ">Chilli Mogo </option>
                              <option value="Chilli Paneer">Chilli Paneer</option>
                              <option value="Cocktail Vegetable Samosa">Cocktail Vegetable Samosa</option>
                              <option value="Cocktail Vegtable Spring Roll">Cocktail Vegtable Spring Roll</option>
                              <option value="Daal Kachori">Daal Kachori</option>
                              <option value="Fish Pakora">Fish Pakora</option>
                              <option value="Garlic Mushrooms ">Garlic Mushrooms </option>
                              <option value="Gobi Pakora">Gobi Pakora</option>
                              <option value="Hara Bara Tikki">Hara Bara Tikki</option>
                              <option value="Jeera Chicken ">Jeera Chicken </option>
                              <option value="Keema Bhuna">Keema Bhuna</option>
                              <option value="Keema Samosa">Keema Samosa</option>
                              <option value="Keema Spring Roll">Keema Spring Roll</option>
                              <option value="Lamb Seekh Kebabs">Lamb Seekh Kebabs</option>
                              <option value="Masala Chips ">Masala Chips </option>
                              <option value="Masala Lamb Chops">Masala Lamb Chops</option>
                              <option value="Masala Fried Prawns">Masala Fried Prawns</option>
                              <option value="Mutter Keema">Mutter Keema</option>
                              <option value="Palak Pakora">Palak Pakora</option>
                              <option value="Paneer Spring Rolls">Paneer Spring Rolls</option>
                              <option value="Paneer Pakora">Paneer Pakora</option>
                              <option value="Spicy Noodles">Spicy Noodles</option>
                              <option value="Thai Fish Cake">Thai Fish Cake</option>
                              <option value="Tandoori Chicken Tikka ">Tandoori Chicken Tikka </option>
                              <option value="Vegetable Samosa">Vegetable Samosa</option>
                              <option value="Vegetable Spring Roll">Vegetable Spring Roll</option>
                              <option value="Vegetable Tikki">Vegetable Tikki</option>
                              <option value="&lt;none&gt;">&lt;none&gt;</option>
                            </select>
                            <input type="button" id="submit2" onClick="addNew();" value=" + ">
                            </p>
                            <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                    </div> <div id="splitter">
                      <table width="250" border="0">
                        <tr>
                          <td width="250"><span class="asdwd">
                            <label>Mains Options</label>
                          </span></td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                          <td><div id="start"></div>
                            <select name="text[]">
                              <option value="Aloo Bengan">Aloo Bengan</option>
                              <option value="Aloo Gobi">Aloo Gobi</option>
                              <option value="Aloo Methi">Aloo Methi</option>
                              <option value="Aloo Mutter">Aloo Mutter</option>
                              <option value="Aloo Palak ">Aloo Palak </option>
                              <option value="Bhindi Masala">Bhindi Masala</option>
                              <option value="Bombay Aloo">Bombay Aloo</option>
                              <option value="Butter Chicken">Butter Chicken</option>
                              <option value="Channa Curry ">Channa Curry </option>
                              <option value="Chicken Curry">Chicken Curry</option>
                              <option value="Chicken Jalfrazi">Chicken Jalfrazi</option>
                              <option value="Chicken Tikka Masala">Chicken Tikka Masala</option>
                              <option value="Daal Makhani">Daal Makhani</option>
                              <option value="Dum Aloo ">Dum Aloo </option>
                              <option value="Karahi Chicken">Karahi Chicken</option>
                              <option value="Keema Mutter">Keema Mutter</option>
                              <option value="King Prawn Masala">King Prawn Masala</option>
                              <option value="Lamb Curry ">Lamb Curry </option>
                              <option value="Lamb Jalfrezi">Lamb Jalfrezi</option>
                              <option value="Lamb Kofta">Lamb Kofta</option>
                              <option value="Lamb Rogan Josh">Lamb Rogan Josh</option>
                              <option value="Mah Moth Daal ">Mah Moth Daal </option>
                              <option value="Makhani Paneer">Makhani Paneer</option>
                              <option value="Malai Kofta">Malai Kofta</option>
                              <option value="Masala Macchi ">Masala Macchi </option>
                              <option value="Masar Daal">Masar Daal</option>
                              <option value="Methi Chicken">Methi Chicken</option>
                              <option value="Methi Gosht">Methi Gosht</option>
                              <option value="Mixed Vegetable Sabji">Mixed Vegetable Sabji</option>
                              <option value="Mutter Paneer">Mutter Paneer</option>
                              <option value="Palak Chicken">Palak Chicken</option>
                              <option value="Palak Gosht">Palak Gosht</option>
                              <option value="Palak Paneer">Palak Paneer</option>
                              <option value="Paneer Jalfrezi">Paneer Jalfrezi</option>
                              <option value="Shahi Paneer">Shahi Paneer</option>
                              <option value="Tarka Daal">Tarka Daal</option>
                              <option value="Vegetable Kofta">Vegetable Kofta</option>
                              <option value="&lt;none&gt;">&lt;none&gt;</option>
                            </select>
                            <input type="button" id="submit2" onClick="addNew();" value=" + ">
                            </p>
                            <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
                        </tr>
                      </table>
                    </div>
                    <p>&nbsp;</p>
                    <p>&nbsp;</p>
                    <tr>
                      <td colspan="2" rowspan="3">

            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <p>&nbsp;</p>
            <table width="563" border="0" align="left">
              <tr>
                <td width="274"><span class="asdwd">
                  <label>Dessert Options</label>
                </span></td>
                <td width="279"><span class="asdwd">
                  <label>Accompliments Options</label>
                </span></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td><div id="des"></div>
                  <select name="text[]2">
                    <option value="Desset**">Desset**</option>
                    <option value="Fruit Salad">Fruit Salad</option>
                    <option value="Gajar Ka Halwa">Gajar Ka Halwa</option>
                    <option value="Gulab Jaman">Gulab Jaman</option>
                    <option value="Kulfi">Kulfi</option>
                    <option value="Rasmalia">Rasmalia</option>
                    <option value="&lt;none&gt;">&lt;none&gt;</option>
                  </select>
                  <input type="button" id="submit2" onClick="addNew();" value=" + ">
                  </p>
                  <p>&nbsp;</p></td>
                <td><div id="accomp"></div>
                  <select name="text[]2">
                    <option value="Bhatura ">Bhatura </option>
                    <option value="Cucumber Cumin Raita Yoghurt">Cucumber Cumin Raita                                       Yoghurt</option>
                    <option value="Jeera Rice">Jeera Rice</option>
                    <option value="Mixed Vegetable Rice">Mixed Vegetable Rice</option>
                    <option value="Paratha">Paratha</option>
                    <option value="Pilau Rice">Pilau Rice</option>
                    <option value="Plain Natural Yoghurt ">Plain Natural Yoghurt </option>
                    <option value="Plain Rice">Plain Rice</option>
                    <option value="Puri">Puri</option>
                    <option value="Roti">Roti</option>
                    <option value="Salad Dhai Yoghurt">Salad Dhai Yoghurt</option>
                    <option value="Tandoori Naan">Tandoori Naan</option>
                    <option value="&lt;none&gt;">&lt;none&gt;</option>
                  </select>
                  <input type="button" id="submit2" onClick="addNew();" value=" + ">
                  </p>
                  <p>&nbsp;</p></form></td>
              </tr>
```

JS Breakfast Opt

```
var counter = 0;

function addNew(e) {

 var countAll = document.getElementsByTagName("select").length - 1;

  var lastSelectBox = document.getElementsByTagName("select")[countAll];

  var items = lastSelectBox.innerHTML;

 // Get the main Div in which all the other divs will be added
 var mainContainer = document.getElementById('break');

// Create a new div for holding text and button input elements
var newDiv = document.createElement('div');

// Create a new text input

var newText = document.createElement('select');
newText.type = "select"; 
newText.setAttribute("name", "text[]");

newText.innerHTML = items;


 // Create buttons for creating and removing inputs
 var newAddButton = document.createElement('input');
  newAddButton.type = "button";
  newAddButton.value = " + ";
  newAddButton.id = "submit2";


  // Append new text input to the newDiv
 newDiv.appendChild(newText);

  // Append new button inputs to the newDiv
  newDiv.appendChild(newAddButton);


  // Append newDiv input to the mainContainer div
  mainContainer.appendChild(newDiv);

  // Add a handler to button for deleting the newDiv from the mainContainer
  newAddButton.onclick = addNew;


  };
```

STARTER OPT JS

```
      var counter = 0;

     function addNew(e) {

     var countAll = document.getElementsByTagName("select").length - 1;

     var lastSelectBox = document.getElementsByTagName("select")[countAll];

     var items = lastSelectBox.innerHTML;

     // Get the main Div in which all the other divs will be added
     var mainContainer = document.getElementById('start');

     // Create a new div for holding text and button input elements
     var newDiv = document.createElement('div');

     // Create a new text input
     var newText = document.createElement('select');
     newText.type = "select"; 
     newText.setAttribute("name", "text[]");

     newText.innerHTML = items;

     //for testing

     // Create buttons for creating and removing inputs
     var newAddButton = document.createElement('input');
     newAddButton.type = "button";
     newAddButton.value = " + ";
     newAddButton.id = "submit2";

     // Append new text input to the newDiv
     newDiv.appendChild(newText);

     // Append new button inputs to the newDiv
     newDiv.appendChild(newAddButton);

     // Append newDiv input to the mainContainer div
     mainContainer.appendChild(newDiv);

     // Add a handler to button for deleting the newDiv from the mainContainer
     newAddButton.onclick = addNew;
    };
```

MAIN OPT JS

```
      var counter = 0;

  function addNew(e) {

    var countAll = document.getElementsByTagName("select").length - 1;

    var lastSelectBox = document.getElementsByTagName("select")[countAll];

    var items = lastSelectBox.innerHTML;

    // Get the main Div in which all the other divs will be added
    var mainContainer = document.getElementById('main');

    // Create a new div for holding text and button input elements
    var newDiv = document.createElement('div');

    // Create a new text input

    var newText = document.createElement('select');
    newText.type = "select"; 
    newText.setAttribute("name", "text[]");

    newText.innerHTML = items;

    //for testing

    // Create buttons for creating and removing inputs
    var newAddButton = document.createElement('input');
    newAddButton.type = "button";
    newAddButton.value = " + ";
    newAddButton.id = "submit2";

    // Append new text input to the newDiv
    newDiv.appendChild(newText);

    // Append new button inputs to the newDiv
    newDiv.appendChild(newAddButton);

    // Append newDiv input to the mainContainer div
    mainContainer.appendChild(newDiv);

    // Add a handler to button for deleting the newDiv from the mainContainer
    newAddButton.onclick = addNew;

    };
```

DESSERT OPT JS

```
      var counter = 0;

      function addNew(e) {

      var countAll = document.getElementsByTagName("select").length - 1;

      var lastSelectBox = document.getElementsByTagName("select")[countAll];

      var items = lastSelectBox.innerHTML;

      // Get the main Div in which all the other divs will be added
     var mainContainer = document.getElementById('des');

      // Create a new div for holding text and button input elements
        var newDiv = document.createElement('div');

      // Create a new text input

      var newText = document.createElement('select');
       newText.type = "select"; 
      newText.setAttribute("name", "text[]");

      newText.innerHTML = items;

      //for testing

      // Create buttons for creating and removing inputs
      var newAddButton = document.createElement('input');
      newAddButton.type = "button";
      newAddButton.value = " + ";
      newAddButton.id = "submit2";

      // Append new text input to the newDiv
      newDiv.appendChild(newText);

      // Append new button inputs to the newDiv
      newDiv.appendChild(newAddButton);

      // Append newDiv input to the mainContainer div
      mainContainer.appendChild(newDiv);

      // Add a handler to button for deleting the newDiv from the mainContainer
     newAddButton.onclick = addNew;

     };
```

ACCOMP OPT JS

```
      var counter = 0;

  function addNew(e) {

    var countAll = document.getElementsByTagName("select").length - 1;

    var lastSelectBox = document.getElementsByTagName("select")[countAll];

    var items = lastSelectBox.innerHTML;

    // Get the main Div in which all the other divs will be added
    var mainContainer = document.getElementById('accomp');

    // Create a new div for holding text and button input elements
    var newDiv = document.createElement('div');

    // Create a new text input

    var newText = document.createElement('select');
    newText.type = "select"; 
    newText.setAttribute("name", "text[]");

    newText.innerHTML = items;

    //for testing

    // Create buttons for creating and removing inputs
    var newAddButton = document.createElement('input');
    newAddButton.type = "button";
    newAddButton.value = " + ";
    newAddButton.id = "submit2";




    // Append new text input to the newDiv
    newDiv.appendChild(newText);

    // Append new button inputs to the newDiv
    newDiv.appendChild(newAddButton);


    // Append newDiv input to the mainContainer div
    mainContainer.appendChild(newDiv);

   // Add a handler to button for deleting the newDiv from the mainContainer
    newAddButton.onclick = addNew;


    };
```

I can provide the actual files if that makes it easier for you to understand. Guessing it's something to do with the duplication.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need all these JS files, create a generic AddSelect function and pass to it the div you want to append the select.

```
function addInput(divName){
          var newdiv = document.createElement('div');
          newdiv.innerHTML = "Entry " + (counter + 1) + " <br><input type='text' name='myInputs[]'>";
          document.getElementById(divName).appendChild(newdiv);
}
```

Copy/paste code is a bad habit :)

Comment: Hi Im unsure of how to do that